# Re-directing a user if they submit a URL shortener

Tags: php

I'm trying to re-direct a user if `$displayurl`  is equal to bit.ly, goo.gl,  or owl.ly.  It's not working.  Is there anything wrong with the IF statement below?

```
$site1 = 'http://' . $cleanurl;

$displayurl = parse_url($site1, PHP_URL_HOST);


if ($displayurl == array(bit.ly, goo.gl, owl.ly))
{

   session_write_close();
   header("Location:http://www.domain.com/directory/file.php");
   exit;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to use this code:

```
$domain = array("bit.ly", "goo.gl", "owl.ly");
if (in_array($displayurl, $domain)) {
   session_write_close();
   header("Location:http://www.domain.com/directory/file.php");
   exit;
}
```